# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online Report created and attached to email

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, workflow, dynamics-crm-online

Does anyone know if it is possible set up a Dialog in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online that will run a report on a specific record after its creation and then attach that report to an outgoing email.

I have two out of three portions of this process figured out. I can create the report and then have the same dialog email out information from it, but having it take the extra step of adding a report is a bit more of a challenge.

I'm considering writing a custom workflow/dialog, but before I start I wanted to ask.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to write a custom workflow activity in CRM Online, this is only possible for on-premise deployments.

Comment: Although this is something which is due to be supported in the [CRM Q2 2012 update](https://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/lostinthoughtsofcrm/archive/2012/02/06/crm-anywhere-q2-2012-service-update-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) (now due at the end of 2012).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can now create Custom Workflow Actions for CRM Online,  It needs to be compiled using Microsoft .NET Framework 4 PU3 (platform update 3) or higher. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328515.aspx)

This was scheduled for release with Rollup 9 although finding authoritative information on this is thin on the ground.  So if it's not there right now it will be in the near future.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/10762.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-update-rollup-9-beta-is-here.aspx